# Range as a passed parameter in AppleScript?

Tags: function, applescript

Is it possible to pass a range as a parameter in AppleScript? Here's a sample of the code I'm trying to use:

```applescript
on getCellAddress(TheRange)
    set TheText to get address of (TheRange)
    return TheText
end getCellAddress

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    
    activate
    activate object workbook "Workbook.xlsx"
    activate object worksheet "Sheet"
    
    set LabelRangeStart to (find (used range of active sheet) what "Name")
    
    set LabelRangeStartAddr to my getCellAddress(LabelRangeStart)
    
end tell
```

With this syntax, I get the error:

```
The variable TheText is not defined." number -2753 from "TheText
```

Comment: **AppleScript** doesn’t have ranges, but in this case you are talking about **MicroSoft Excel**.  Note that _any_ application terminology, such as what you are trying to use in your `getCellAddress` handler, needs to be targeted by using a `tell` statement.

Comment: "tell application "Microsoft Excel"" was what i was missing inside the function. Just adding that line made it work. Thank you!!

Comment: If that made it work, you can self answer your question so other people searching for the same thing can find an answer without reading the comments.